# Python, how to concatenate 2 strings of same value, 0

Tags: python, concatenation

Post for Python.
I did read other posts and sure this isn't a duplicate

I created two variables in my Python and they both have the string 0. I tried with 2 different strings of 1 and 0 and when I concatenate them I get 10. But when I concatenate 0 and 0 I get another 0.
Code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
b = int(str(a)+str(b))
print(b)
```

Output: 0.
I would like the output to be 00

Comment: `print(str(a) + str(b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having leading zeros in a number will be removed. It won't change the value so Python just removes them.

As you can see:

```
>>> 0123
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
>>>
```

Putting `0` in front of a literal gives an error. But if you just do:

```
>>> int('0123')
123
>>>
```

It would automatically strip the zeros.

To fix it don't change it to a integer:

```
a = 0
b = 0
x = str(a) + str(b)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
00
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the conversion back to int

```py
a = 0
b = 0
b = str(a)+str(b)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

in this line `b = int(str(a)+str(b))` you convert `00` to int and `00` in int convert to `0`.
you can change your code like below then you get your desire output:

```
a = 0
b = 0
print(str(a)+str(b))
```

also maybe this example helps you:

```
print(00)
# 0
print("00")
# 00
```

Comment: TIL leading zeros are allowed on a zero! They're not allowed on any other number, even if it would be unambiguous...

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks for your comment. do you say `print(00)` is not correct? yes when I am typing, the left zero converts to red color but I don't get error and code run correctly on jupyter

Comment: TIL = today I learned; using `00` is correct in Python 3, but I didn't know that (and wasn't expecting it to be)

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks a lot `MAN`, I don't know what is meaning of TIL :)))

Comment: Today you learned that `TIL` means `Today I Learned`

Comment: @ExtraFishness yes I didn't that ;)))) TIL, TIL mean Today I Learned

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a lot of terminology here, I suggest you follow a tutorial on types in python (or read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html))

As to your problem. You are not storing strings in a and b, you are storing integers:

```
# These will be integers:
a = 0
b = 0

# These will be strings:
a = '0'
b = '0'
```

notice the quotes on the strings vs the no quotes on the integers.

Then you do this part:

```
b = int(str(a)+str(b))
```

you are casting a and b to a string (both containing `'0'`), and concatinating them, creating the string `'00'`. that is what you want to print, but then you cast them back to integers using `int()`. and when you cast a string with leading zeros to int, the leading zeros are omitted, leaving you back with a '0'.

in conclusion, you can fix your code by removing unnecessary type casts, and using correct typing for your variables:

```
a = '0'
b = '0'
b = a + b
print(b)
```

or if you need a and b as integers:

```
a = 0
b = 0
print(str(a) + str(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want output to be '00', keep b as a string. When you convert it to int, Python simplifies it and simply prints a 0.

New Code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
b = str(a)+str(b)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because mathematically 00 also means 0. so when converting it to int() type it just takes it as a 0.

so in the print statement don't convert into int() let it be in string.

so print(str(a)+str(b))